# How do I convert a character code back to a character?

Tags: ruby, string

How to I get the Fixnum returned by the following:

```
"abc"[2]
```

Back into a character?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This will do it (if n is an integer):

```
n.chr
```

Answer (score 4):

Be careful because Ruby 1.9 and later will return a single-character string for `"abc"[2]`, which will not respond to the `chr` method. You could do this instead:

```
"abc"[2,1]
```

Be sure to read up on the powerful and multifaceted [String#[] method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000786).